# Open liferay's portlet in pop-up and after success refresh the calling portlet

Tags: modal-dialog, liferay, refresh, liferay-6

We have a requirement to open liferay's add/edit folder/document screen in a dialog pop-up of our custom plugin portlet.

And after successful (no exceptions or errors) save it should automatically close the pop-up and refresh just our plugin portlet on the page.

Following is the code we have used to open liferay's pop-up:

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="addFolderURL" portletName="<%=PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY %>" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_folder" />
    <liferay-portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
    <liferay-portlet:param name="repositoryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(repositoryId) %>" />
    <liferay-portlet:param name="parentFolderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<%
String addFolderJavascript = "javascript:Liferay.Util.openWindow({dialog: {destroyOnHide: true}, id: 'addFolderPopUpId', title: '" 
                                + ((folder != null) ? UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "add-subfolder") : UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "add-folder")) 
                                + "', uri: '" + HtmlUtil.escapeJS(addFolderURL) + "'});";
%>

<aui:a href="<%= addFolderJavascript %>" label='<%= (folder != null) ? "subfolder" : "folder" %>' />
```

The difficulty is how would we know when the add/edit document is successful, how would we close the pop-up and then refresh the portlet since we don't have any control over the add/edit screen coming from liferay. And even if we do it through hook the problem is how to know the success/failure of the document.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never thought the answer would be in Liferay's code itself and was pretty simple.

Liferay also uses such a functionality in Asset Publisher portlet, as shown below:

[image]

So liferay after adding the blogs, document etc closes the pop-up and refreshes the asset-publisher portlet. It does this with a simple redirect trick.

Three things:

1. you require a jsp which would have the redirect and close script.
2. a redirect url which will call the above jsp after successful save.

   In liferay `redirect` parameter is always passed as a parameter to almost all action requests and on successful save it redirects to the URL passed in this parameter
3. the popup-id which can be referenced from the jsp.

The jsp is [/asset_publisher/add_asset_redirect.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/asset_publisher/add_asset_redirect.jsp) and its code is as shown below which can be used in your plugin as it is (<sub>I have used comments to explain somethings</sub>):

```
<%
String redirect = request.getParameter("redirect");

redirect = PortalUtil.escapeRedirect(redirect);

Portlet selPortlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById(company.getCompanyId(), portletDisplay.getId());
%>

<aui:script use="aui-base">
    Liferay.fire(
        'closeWindow', // closes the pop-up window
        {
            id: '<portlet:namespace />editAsset', // the id of the pop-up which we gave
            portletAjaxable: <%= selPortlet.isAjaxable() %>,

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="<%= redirect != null %>">
                    redirect: '<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(redirect) %>' // redirects the page to this URL
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    refresh: '<%= portletDisplay.getId() %>' // refreshes only the portlet
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

So now lets achieve what we intend to step-by-step in our plugin:

1. have a jsp similar to add_asset_redirect.jsp in your plugin.
2. build the redirect url like:

   ```java
   <%
   PortletURL customRedirectURL = liferayPortletResponse.createLiferayPortletURL(themeDisplay.getPlid(), portletDisplay.getId(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE, false);

   customRedirectURL.setParameter("mvcPath", "/html/common/add_asset_redirect.jsp"); // mvcPath so that your custom portlet's render() calls this jsp when a redirect from liferay's page happens
   /* customRedirectURL.setParameter("redirect", themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()); // set this if you want to redirect to a certain page, if only refresh is your motto then leave this commented. */
   customRedirectURL.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.POP_UP);

   String customRedirect = customRedirectURL.toString();

   // popUp-id while opening the pop-up. should be same as that in add_asset_redirect.jsp
   String customPopUpId = renderResponse.getNamespace() + "editAsset";
   %>
   ```
3. build the code to open the pop-up:

   ```
   <liferay-portlet:renderURL var="addFolderURL" portletName="<%=PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY %>" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>">
       <liferay-portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_folder" />
       <liferay-portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= customRedirect %>" />
       <liferay-portlet:param name="repositoryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(repositoryId) %>" />
       <liferay-portlet:param name="parentFolderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
   </liferay-portlet:renderURL>

   <%
   String addFolderJavascript = "javascript:Liferay.Util.openWindow({dialog: {destroyOnHide: true}, id: '"
                                   + customPopUpId +"', title: '" 
                                   + ((folder != null) ? UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "add-subfolder") : UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "add-folder")) 
                                   + "', uri: '" + HtmlUtil.escapeJS(addFolderURL) + "'});";
   %>

   <aui:a href="<%= addFolderJavascript %>" label='<%= (folder != null) ? "subfolder" : "folder" %>' />
   ```
4. that's all. Go check-it out.

Hope this helps.